# How to access a global function (Vue.prototype.myFn) from another function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am on a nuxt.js project and trying to create global functions and I am this error:

```
Cannot read property '$toggleBodyClass' of undefined
```

Here is my code (plugins/globals.js):

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.prototype.$toggleBodyClass = (addRemoveClass, className) => {
  const elBody = document.body;

  if (addRemoveClass === 'addClass') {
    elBody.classList.add(className);
  } else {
    elBody.classList.remove(className);
  }
};

Vue.prototype.$setModalBackdrop = () => {
  this.$toggleBodyClass('addClass', 'modal-open'); // ** How to make this work? **
};
```

This work just fine when I use it in my component (components/myComp.vue):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="handelClick">Toggle Class</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$toggleBodyClass('addClass', 'modal-open');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

please help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Vue.prototype.$toggleBodyClass` instead of `this.$toggleBodyClass`?

Comment: @SamiHult wow! that simply worked :) thanks. Can you add this as answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just change your code from

```
this.$toggleBodyClass
```

to

```
Vue.prototype.$toggleBodyClass
```

Comment: This is quite ugly solution.

Answer (score 2):

In nuxt you can use inject function to make it accessible from context, vuex store etc also [inject](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject)

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('myInjectedFunction', (string) => console.log('That was easy!', string))
}
```